# Subplots in pgfplots groupplot are unaligned when using the colorbrewer package

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to create a `groupplot` with PGFPlots where each subplot uses colors from the `colorbrewer` library. When adding the `\pgfplotsset{cycle/list/Set1-5}` the two subplots are unaligned and I get the error message:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named is known.
See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...               
l.22             \addplot
                          coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
```

I've tried several different variations such as adding the `cycle list/Set1-5` as an option to `\nextgroupplot` directly but with the same result. I've also tried different color maps but with the same result. If I only add colorbrewer to the first plot it works fine but when I add it to the second I get this error. The colors in the plots turn out correctly but the subplots are unaligned.

Unaligned subplots with `colorbrewer`:

[image: Unaligned subplots due to colorbrewer]

Aligned subplots without `colorbrewer`:

[image: Aligned subplots without colorbrewer]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikz}

% I guess that I only need one of these
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

% Line that causes the error
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/group/every plot/.append style = {%
    cycle list/Set1-5}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2},height=3cm,width=3cm]
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `cycle list/...` to the `\nextgroupplot` options doesn't work when you want to use different cycle lists for the plot. (Not sure if this is a bug.) But you could initialize all the needed/wanted colormaps in advance and then just activate the corresponding cycle lists in the above mentioned options ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        colorbrewer,
        groupplots,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.14,
        % initialize colormaps that you want to use later
        % (either in colormaps or as cycle lists)
        colormap/Set1-5,
        colormap/Set2-5,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 2,
        },
        height=3cm,
        width=3cm,
    ]
        \nextgroupplot[
            % activate cycle list you want to use
            cycle list name=Set1-5,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
        \nextgroupplot[
            cycle list name=Set2-5,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I would like to have two different color maps for the two subplots is that possible somehow?

Comment: @Martin, sure you can do this. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried to add cycle list/.. directly as a \nextgrouplot option as you mentioned but it did not work however this worked fine and accomplish the exact same thing. Answer accepted.